# select column value with variable

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, execute

I want to select some data from tables . 
For that , i write this procedure :

```
create or replace procedure find_and_insert
  colname varchar2(4000);
  var varchar2(4000);
  colval varchar2(4000);
begin
  colname := 'COUNTRY_ID';
  var := 'select distinct(colname) into colval from HR.countries where colname = '||'AR'||';';
  execute immediate var;  
end;
```

But it can not work . It return 'COUNTRY_ID' into colval , not data of COUNTRY_ID ;
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the procedure executes successfully. You will get `colname : invalid identifier` error.

Since colname is a variable here, you should concatenate it to your select string.

```
var := 'select distinct('||colname||') 
        into colval 
        from HR.countries 
        where '||colname ||'= AR';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, with the statement colname := 'COUNTRY_ID';

You are simply assigning a string 'COUNTRY_ID' to a varchar2 type variable colname. In short the program is giving you the correct output for what you have written. I recommend you write as :

```
'select distinct('||colname||') 
 into colval 
 from HR.countries 
 where '||colname ||'= AR';
```

as mentioned in the above answer. Also i see that you are accessing the table countries as HR.countries so I sense that you better access the column name in your query in a similar fashion, as

```
'select distinct(HR.countries.'||colname||') 
 into colval 
 from HR.countries 
 where HR.countries.'||colname ||'= AR';
```